# How do I access this part of the Google Maps via the API?

Tags: google-maps

In the image below, what's the term for the "Boulder Farmers' Market" label for a particular marker? Is there information somewhere on how to create this for each marker via the Google Maps API?

[image]

Comment: Wow, thought this would be an easy 15 points for someone. :) No idea as to what this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting any answers is because its a strange questions to answer.

You're using the google maps app.  The "label" you speak of is just the name of the place that google has found that matches your search query wrapped in its own design. You can't access this design from the API.

You would have to create your own custom infowindows. [Here's one example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html)